# got an error with while loop in php

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone help me take a look? I want to fetch a number out but i get this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ']' in E:\Software\Xampp\htdocs\pme\main\user_online.php on line 12

here is my code

```
<?php 

    include '../config.php';

    $sql= mysqli_query($connection,' select * from session');
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

    while($extract = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo
        "<div class='left-total-user-online' id='left-total-user-online'>

            total user online : " .$extract[$row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);]. "</div>";

    }

?>
```

Comment: You already declared this `$row = mysqli_num_rows($sql)` there's no need for it. Just echo out the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making life much more complicated than is necessary. All you need to code is

```
<?php 

    include '../config.php';

    $sql= mysqli_query($connection,' select * from session');
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

    echo "<div class='left-total-user-online' id='left-total-user-online'>
            total user online : $row</div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: [*Which I said in so many words, lol!...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374821/got-an-error-with-while-loop-in-php#comment62260981_37374821) - wink.

Comment: Yes you did. Was busy copy/paste/trowing away while you were saying it my old mucker

Comment: well, you put in more work than I did. I just wanted to make them think and figure it out for themselves ;-)

Comment: ...well of course it did ;-)

Comment: haha ~~ i still new in code and still studying diploma try to learn some new language for my future ～ and thank you for your comment